# Objective C, customization UIButton, error NSGenericException

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I want to customize a `UIButton` and write the class blow.

In Interface builder I use this class as `UIButton` custom class but get error

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'This coder requires that replaced objects be returned from initWithCoder:'
```

The custom class:

```
-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
if((self = [super init])){
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0;
    self.clipsToBounds = true;
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:69/255 green:83/255 blue:153/255 alpha:1];
}
return nil;
}

-(void) setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted {
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted];

    if(highlighted){
       self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:83/255 green:98/255 blue:178/255 alpha:1];
    } else {
       self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:69/255 green:83/255 blue:153/255 alpha:1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the method

```
-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
if((self = [super init])){
self.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0;
self.clipsToBounds = true;
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:69/255 green:83/255 blue:153/255 alpha:1];
}
return nil;
}
```

Last line should be

```
return self;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're getting that error specifically, but I do know that everything you're trying to do with this custom class can be done directly in Interface Builder itself. If you do not have a good reason to be creating a custom subclass of UIButton in this case, I suggest you simply use IB to do it.

The one attribute that's a little trickier to set in IB is the `layer.cornerRadius` since there isn't a graphical setting for it, but it can be set using the `User Defined Runtime Attributes` section of the `Identity Inspector`. Simply add a new row with `layer.cornerRadius`as the `Key Path`, `Number` as the `Type`, and `4` (in your case) as the `Value`.

Comment: I find the mistake is I return nil in the method initWithCoder. return self will be the solution.  If you want to customize button highlight state, you have to customize the UIButton class

Comment: Glad you found your nil issue. Just so you know though, you can customize all of the built-in states of a UIButton (Highlighted, Focused, Selected, Disabled) through Interface Builder. You do not need to make a subclass to do so. Under the Attributes Inspector there is a `State Config` option. If you set it to `Highlighted` you can then set the attributes that will be used for that state. You can set all the states in this way. Then when you set the button to be selected, highlighted, disabled, etc. it will use your custom config. I hope that makes your life a little easier!

Answer (score 0):

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder 
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0;
        self.clipsToBounds = true;
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:69/255 green:83/255 blue:153/255   alpha:1];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Try this.